# Are planes without $n$ points isomorphic as algebraic varieties for different n?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Denote $\mathbb A^d_n=\mathbb A^d \setminus \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ (the algebraic variety over the field $k$). Then $\mathbb A^1_n$ are not isomorphic over $k$ for different $n$, probably because the multiplicative group of global invertible functions is $k^* \times \mathbb Z^n$. For $d \geqslant 2$, $\mathbb A^d_n$ is affine iff $n=0$ (by "algebraic Hartog's lemma"). The questions are the following:

1. Are $\mathbb A^1_n$ isomorphic for different choices of points?
2. For $d \geqslant 2$, are $\mathbb A^d_n$ not isomorphic for different $n$?
3. Is there a general method to compare varieties, explicitly covered by affine ones?

Comment: The automorphism group of $\mathbb{A}^1$ acts 2-transitively, so you can remove any two points you like. I don't know whether you can remove any three points you like, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For two different choices  $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$ of your $n$ points  the varieties $X=\mathbb A^1 \setminus \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ and $Y=\mathbb A^1 \setminus \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ will not be isomorphic as soon as  $n\geq 3$.  Here is why:

Any isomorphism $f:X\to Y$ is a birational map and thus extends to a biregular  automorphism $F:\mathbb P^1\to \mathbb P^1$.  (Hartshorne, Chapter I, Proposition 6.8)
 That automorphism should biject $\{\infty,x_1\,x_2,x_3\}$ onto $\{\infty,y_i,y_j,y_k\}$ , which is impossible in general.
Indeed,  the cross-ratio $(\infty,x_1;x_2,x_3)$ of the four points $\infty,x_1\,x_2,x_3$ will not be equal to  $(\infty,y_i;y_j,y_k)$ in general (even  allowing for some permutation of those points) while any automorphism of $\mathbb P^1$ **must** preserve the cross-ratio of four given points.